# Gridview DataKeyNames

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to include the DataKeyname "Number" onto a response.redirect in a gridview selectedindexchanged so that i can pass it to the next page? I'm currently using this code to pass data and the gridview is currently setup to display the number in the row. I want to hide the column for "number" and use the datakeyname instead. Thanks!

```
Response.Redirect("RoundingEntry.aspx?Room=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text & "&Name=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text & "&Number=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text & "&Member=" & DDMember.SelectedValue & "&Unit=" & DDUnit.SelectedValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, you can use the `GridView.SelectedIndex` property to get the correct data key out of the `GridView.DataKeys` collection.

Might I also suggest cleaning that up, so that it's not all one long line of code?

```
Sub CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim room As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
    Dim name As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text
    ' This is the one I've changed, to grab the DataKey of the selected row
    Dim number As String = GridView1.DataKeys(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Value.ToString()
    Dim member As String = DDMember.SelectedValue.ToString()
    Dim unit As String = DDUnit.SelectedValue.ToString()
    
    Response.Redirect("RoundingEntry.aspx?Room=" & room & _
                                        "&Name=" & name & _
                                        "&Number=" & number & _
                                        "&Member=" & member & _
                                        "&Unit=" & unit)
End Sub
```